# optimalization problems

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I do not understand in the optimization problems the following steps. Let us say we have the problem
$$\min(\text{or}\max) f(x)$$ subject to
$$p^{t}x=b$$
in some textbooks, I saw the Lagrange function in the form:
$$L(x,\lambda)=f(x)+\lambda (p^{t}x-b)$$ $$L(x,\lambda)=f(x)-\lambda (p^{t}x-b)$$ $$L(x,\lambda)=f(x)+\lambda (b-p^{t}x)$$ $$L(x,\lambda)=f(x)+\lambda (b-p^{t}x).$$ I am absolutely confused. It gives me a hard time What are the rules which form should I use in different situations?

Comment: It is entirely up to you, just pick one and stick to it. There is no one choice of signs, it is all a matter of convention.

Comment: You mean that I can choose absolutely arbitrary any of the four choices? Well, how I will recognize the difference in min or max function? You mean I can ignore it?  It does not matter if I am supposed maximize or minimize a function?

Comment: Certainly you can do all you want with either form. The "worst" that can happen is that you will get dual values of opposite sign, but that is all a matter of convention. Personally I would never remember all these rules for taking plus/minus/less than/greater then when working with duality so I just derive it from the start and any choices that have to be made just present themselves. You only have equality constraints, so even less to worry about.